# ADAL java library for access token not returning groups and roles

Tags: java, active-directory, token, adal

I am trying to get groups and roles for an Active Directory using the ADAL4J library and the sample project that I am referring to is 
the GitHub AzureAD sample project [azure-activedirectory-library-for-java](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).

The response that I get is a token that has the following:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.windows.net",
  "iss": "[redacted for stackoverflow post]",
  "iat": 1474924521,
  "nbf": 1474924521,
  "exp": 1474928421,
  "appid": "MyApplicationObjectId from AD",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "e_exp": 10800,
  "idp": "[redacted for stack overflow post]",
  "oid": "68467740-2af5-43ab-8bfb-362b494956c5",
  "roles": [
    "Device.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Domain.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
  "sub": "68467740-2af5-43ab-8bfb-362b494956c5",
  "tid": "e536c1ed-4822-4b88-8c01-9f14c1c583e3",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

However, I am expecting the following claims in the access token as well:

```
"groups": [
    "8c335044-b534-4cfa-a816-c62588ca169e",
    "68ff7ec2-db1b-45cc-afb4-785723f9a2db",
    "a79ed389-c46f-4782-9752-90f4871e4b15",
    "657b2f05-15f2-4849-a831-c42ecdf7db13"
  ],
"roles": [
    "add-or-view-org-admin"
  ],
```

Since the application that my user is trying to access is a web application, I send the client secret in the request as follows:

```
private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
    String username, String password) throws Exception
{
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, true, service);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(
            CLIENT_ID, "Client Key for my Application from Active Directory");
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
            "https://graph.windows.net", clientCred, null);
        result = future.get();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }
    if (result == null) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException(
                "authentication result was null");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Has anybody been able to do this using such a Java client?

I need to have it using Java as I need to run integration tests for the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Integration Tests to get access token for accessing Web Applications configured in Azure Active Directory

1. Get the PublicClient.java from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-native-headless
2. Follow steps in the README.md and for allowing the Native Application to request token for the Web Application configured in AAD.
3. Click Add Application, Select SHOW All Apps, Click the OK button ( that shows a tickmark ) and select the application that you have registered.
4. Give the permissions for this application .("Access Inventory Insights")
   Save the changes
5. Use the following in the PublicClient.java

private final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";

private final static String CLIENT_ID = "675a9f3e-c78a-48cc-9151-59d14ac2205b";

Future < AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken
("Client Id of the Application User is trying to access." , CLIENT_ID, username, password, null );